# Unable to deploy Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions for Firebase for a few years. Today, I updated the firebase-tools to latest i.e. `9.10.0` and since then, I am not able to deploy any of the Cloud Functions for Firebase. Below is the console output:

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (96.9 KB) for uploading
i  scheduler: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  pubsub: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  pubsub: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function sendFeedbackEmail(us-central1)...
i  functions: scheduler job firebase-schedule-publishAwsWorkerQueueLength-us-central1 is up to date, no changes required
✔  functions[publishAwsWorkerQueueLength(us-central1)]: Successful upsert schedule operation.
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function sendPushNotification(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function generateAuthenticationToken(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function isUserRunningMinimumVersion(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function sendVerificationCode(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function sendCodeOnCall(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function verifyCode(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function createUserWithoutMobileNumber(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function verifyCodeForExistingUser(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function addConnections(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function updateConnections(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function getWelcomeAlarms(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function getAdditionalSetupInstructions(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function getBlacklistedCountryCodesForCodeOnCall(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function restoreBlockedAlarms(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function blockExistingAlarms(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function addWelcomeAlarms(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function deleteAccount(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function findDeletedAlarms(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function getWhatsNewBetweenReleases(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function updateCreatorTimezoneForAlarms(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function addContact(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function deleteInvitedContact(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function deleteGalarmContact(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function getPreviousOccurrencesOfAlarmBetweenTime(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function editInvitedContactName(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function editGalarmContactName(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function verifyPurchases(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function cancelSubscription(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function appDownload(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function publishAwsWorkerQueueLength(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function generateAvatarThumbnail(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function processImage(us-central1)...

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    sendFeedbackEmail(us-central1)
    editGalarmContactName(us-central1)
    isUserRunningMinimumVersion(us-central1)
    verifyPurchases(us-central1)
    verifyCodeForExistingUser(us-central1)
    blockExistingAlarms(us-central1)
    getBlacklistedCountryCodesForCodeOnCall(us-central1)
    deleteAccount(us-central1)
    generateAuthenticationToken(us-central1)
    publishAwsWorkerQueueLength(us-central1)
    createUserWithoutMobileNumber(us-central1)
    getWhatsNewBetweenReleases(us-central1)
    processImage(us-central1)
    addConnections(us-central1)
    getPreviousOccurrencesOfAlarmBetweenTime(us-central1)
    generateAvatarThumbnail(us-central1)
    getAdditionalSetupInstructions(us-central1)
    addContact(us-central1)
    cancelSubscription(us-central1)
    updateConnections(us-central1)
    sendCodeOnCall(us-central1)
    appDownload(us-central1)
    deleteInvitedContact(us-central1)
    getWelcomeAlarms(us-central1)
    verifyCode(us-central1)
    sendPushNotification(us-central1)
    findDeletedAlarms(us-central1)
    editInvitedContactName(us-central1)
    addWelcomeAlarms(us-central1)
    deleteGalarmContact(us-central1)
    sendVerificationCode(us-central1)
    updateCreatorTimezoneForAlarms(us-central1)
    restoreBlockedAlarms(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:sendFeedbackEmail,functions:editGalarmContactName,functions:isUserRunningMinimumVersion,functions:verifyPurchases,functions:verifyCodeForExistingUser,functions:blockExistingAlarms,functions:getBlacklistedCountryCodesForCodeOnCall,functions:deleteAccount,functions:generateAuthenticationToken,functions:publishAwsWorkerQueueLength,functions:createUserWithoutMobileNumber,functions:getWhatsNewBetweenReleases,functions:processImage,functions:addConnections,functions:getPreviousOccurrencesOfAlarmBetweenTime,functions:generateAvatarThumbnail,functions:getAdditionalSetupInstructions,functions:addContact,functions:cancelSubscription,functions:updateConnections,functions:sendCodeOnCall,functions:appDownload,functions:deleteInvitedContact,functions:getWelcomeAlarms,functions:verifyCode,functions:sendPushNotification,functions:findDeletedAlarms,functions:editInvitedContactName,functions:addWelcomeAlarms,functions:deleteGalarmContact,functions:sendVerificationCode,functions:updateCreatorTimezoneForAlarms,functions:restoreBlockedAlarms"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

I haven't made any changes to the functions and I have been deploying these functions successfully before updating the Firebase CLI.

There are no actual errors printed on the console, so , I am not sure what is wrong how to fix the problem.

Please let me know how can I debug/solve this problem.

Comment: We are heavily impacted by this problem. I would request any member from Firebase team to help us resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wait a little bit and deploy again. Sometimes errors like that happen because issues on the Firebase side. After a while it works again without any need from you to do something.

Comment: I have tried many times over the period of an hour or so and then tried again now after 6 hours and still the same problem.

Comment: Could you pls check your firebase functions log in the Firebase Web Console or GCP functions log. Maybe there is more information about it. Did you try to downgrate your firebase-tools version?

Comment: Thanks @Tarik Huber. There were no logs on the Firebase Web Console but there were some logs on the GCP console that pointed to the error due to which the Cloud Function were not deployed. It was a missing `import` statement. Quite stupid that such a simple error is not displayed on the CLI while deploying the functions, neither does it give any indication that the logs may be present on the GCP console.

Comment: Great to hear that you could fix your error :) yea the logs could be improved massively.

Comment: @VarunGupta feel free to [send a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) where error logs are not shown in detail from the CLI (and Firebase Console) when deploying a function. The problem is already solved and a workaround is that logs can be seen on GCP console, but I'd still trust your best judgement for the right urgency just in case you'd file one.